# jQuery code not launched

Tags: jquery, html, onclick

For some reason this trivial jQuery code isn't running. It should display an alert box upon clicking the abc text. What's the error?

```
<html>
<body>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("p#abc").click(function(){
   alert ('abc');
  });
 });
</script>
<p id="abc">abc</p>
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: Are you add jQuery file?

Comment: LOL, that was the reason, thanks

Comment: Try adding the jQuery file like so: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>` before your script tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery file was missing as others pointed out